# parsing data in file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, grep

I have a text file with the following type of data in it below:

```
Example:
10212012115655_113L_-247R_247LRdiff_0;
10212012115657_114L_-246R_246LRdiff_0;
10212012115659_115L_-245R_245LRdiff_0;
10212012113951_319L_-41R_41LRdiff_2;
10212012115701_116L_-244R_244LRdiff_0;
10212012115703_117L_-243R_243LRdiff_0;
10212012115705_118L_-242R_242LRdiff_0;
10212012113947_317L_-43R_43LRdiff_0;
10212012114707_178L_-182R_182LRdiff_3;
10212012115027_278L_-82R_82LRdiff_1;
```

I would like to copy all the data lines that have

```
1) _2 _3 _1 at the end of it into another file along with
2) stripping out the semicolon at the end of it.
```

So at the end the data in the file will be

```
Example:  
10212012113951_319L_-41R_41LRdiff_2
10212012114707_178L_-182R_182LRdiff_3
10212012115027_278L_-82R_82LRdiff_1
```

How can I go about doing this?
I'm using linux ubuntu 10.04 64bit

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/\(.*_[123]\);$/\1/p' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Here's one way using `grep`:

```
grep -oP '.*_(1|2|3)(?=;$)' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Contents of `newfile.txt`:

```
10212012113951_319L_-41R_41LRdiff_2
10212012114707_178L_-182R_182LRdiff_3
10212012115027_278L_-82R_82LRdiff_1
```

Comment: Nice, didn't even think to use `sed` by itself, though I used `sed`'s regex to pull the semi-colon =P. +1!

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer, you can even use `grep` all by itself too.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same and there is only a semi-colon at the very end of each line you can use `grep` to find the lines and then `sed` to replace the `;`:

```
grep -P "_(1|2|3);$" your_file | sed 's/\(.*\);$/\1/' > your_new_file
```

The `-P` in the `grep` command tells it to use the Perl-regex interpreter for parsing. Alternatively, you could use `egrep` (if available).

Answer (score 1):

here is the awk solution if at all you are interested:

```
awk '/_[321];$/{gsub(/;/,"");print}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> awk '/_[321];$/{gsub(/;/,"");print}' temp
10212012113951_319L_-41R_41LRdiff_2
10212012114707_178L_-182R_182LRdiff_3
10212012115027_278L_-82R_82LRdiff_1
```

Comment: That will work given the OPs sample data but to nit-pick - since you only want to remove one ; you should be using sub() rather than gsub() and since you only want to to remove a semi-colon at the end of the line you should include that in the RE and use sub(/;$/,"").

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -c ";" "\n" > newfile
grep '*_[123]$' newfile > newfile
```

This should work. At first you translate all `;` to `\n` and save result to destination file. Then use grep to match the lines only containing `*_[123]` at the end and save matching result to that file again that will replace all previous data. To mark at the end I used `$`.

Some examples using [tr](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-linux-unix-tr-command/) and [grep](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/) in case you are not familiar to it.